# Resolve html properties while parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

How can I remove HTML entities from parsing XML??
Means i am parsing XML but I'm not able to remove `<br/>`, `&nbsp;` etc.

Comment: When posting HTML code, use back-tick ( \`<br/>\` ) to escape them, or they won't show up in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@","withString:@""];
```

Try to use this function, replace symbols witch you want.

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like this?

```
   /**
 * Removes the HTML tags found in the string
 * @param html the string to scan
 *
 * @returns the original string without tags
 */
- (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html {
  NSScanner *thescanner;
  NSString *text = nil;

  thescanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

  while ([thescanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    // find start of tag
    [thescanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL];

    // find end of tag
    [thescanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text];

    // replace the found tag with a space
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text]
                                           withString:@" "];
  } // while //

  return html;
}
```